# How to change user directory name in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, username

Is it possible, and if yes how, to change the name of a user directory in Windows 7?
e.g. change C:\Users\Tim & Carly to C:\Users\Tim_and_Carly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [illustrated guide](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/87555-user-profile-change-default-location.html).

Comment: A text abstraction would be good. I doubt that Seven Forums is going to disappear anytime soon, but it could go down for a while, be down for maintenance, be blocked, etc. which is why link-only answers [are frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143663/why-do-i-get-exactly-the-same-comment-by-different-users-for-my-link-only-answer).