# How to make a browser catch links you click on?

Tags: windows, browser

I [changed my user directory name on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/180023/how-to-change-user-directory-name-in-windows-7) as one of the development tools I'm using couldn't handle spaces in this directory's name. Since then, when I click links or when programs try to pop-up a browser, nothing happens. How can I fix this?

Examples:

- Right click on google talk \ inbox  - doesn't open my default browser with gmail
- Clicking on links people send me in Skype doesn't do anything
- Clicking on links embedded in Word documents
- etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your default browser to something else and back again