# How can I change the name of the C:\Users\username directory?

Tags: windows-8, username

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change user directory name in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/180023/how-to-change-user-directory-name-in-windows-7)
>   [How to rename user folder in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/495290/how-to-rename-user-folder-in-windows-8)

I installed Windows 8 and I wrote my user name in Hebrew. I need to change it to English.

- I have this: `C:\Users\In_Hebrew`
- I need this: `C:\Users\In_English`

How can I do that?